# How can I tell if someone cancelled their subscription to my iOS app?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that people download. How can I tell when people cancel their subscription to the app? Does Apple have an API that notifies me when people cancel their subscription? I’m using in app purchasing.

Comment: What do you mean cancelled?  Turned off auto renew or contacted Apple support and requested a refund - The two cases are handled differently.  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/enabling_server-to-server_notifications and also the receipt that your app can access

Comment: as far as i know (and because of privacy data protection at all) Apple will never tell you if someone cancels your subscription. The only possibility would be if you do an extra button to make it possible to cancel your subscription in the app - but then you don't know when somebody cancels the app via iPhone Settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.